# Duplicate column headers in hana SQL view

Tags: sql, hana

On trying to create the view, I am getting error 'duplicate column name: PXX_ID'. I cannot do an inner join as most of the data in the 2 columns I am joining on don't match and I still need all of the data. Now, I understand this can be avoided by putting aliases for the column but that would make my situation difficult as I have almost 100 tables to be put into the view out of which some will have multiple matching columns and I am already using dynamic SQL to make it work.
Is there any other way I can retain all columns from both tables and still save it in the view?

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: The crux of the issue doesn't seem how standard SQL works (i.e. enforcing unique column names for tables/views) but how your overall use case is mapped to SQL. Mind sharing a bit more about that use case and how dynamic SQL plays into it?

Answer (score 0):

What don't you get?  You have a subquery that selects all the columns from two tables.  Any column name in both tables is going to be duplicated.  At the very least `PXX_ID` is duplicated, because that is used for `JOIN`ing and is clearly in both tables.

Using `select *` in views is a bad idea anyway.  You should list out all the columns.

Comment: I know the column is duplicated but I still want both the duplicated columns in my view. Is there a way to do that? This wouldn't have been an issue in SQL Server but I am using SAP HANA here. I am using select * because this is part of a larger dynamic sql code which will bring in many more tables and columns.

Comment: @RahulBanerjee . . . That is silly, but you would need to use a column alias to give one or both different names.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, using alias is not quite an option for me as I will need to merge close to 100 tables each with 20-25 columns

Comment: SQL Server requires unique column names for views, too. I don't see how this problem would be any different with SQL Server (or any other SQL DB). One thing to note is that some DBMS (HANA among them) allow for simple SELECT statements to have duplicate column names. Could it be that you had this in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to the question posted here is what @Gordon Linhoff already mentioned.

*"It's silly, one shouldn't be doing something like this, and if you do you need to explicitly write out every single column name."*

I fully agree with that.

**BUT ...**

Based on your other recent questions here on SO and in the SAP Community (​especially this question: [Is there a way to create a dynamic flat file?](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13054080/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-dynamic-flat-file.html)) I believe to have an understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

This is my answer to this overall problem;

​I'm assuming that this is related to another question of yours https://answers.sap.com/questions/13054093/duplicate-column-headers-hana.html.

So, in essence, you know some criteria and you know that data matching that criteria are in your database.
Now, you want to get that data out into a single flat file.

This is a wildly unspecific problem description.

One way would be to just go through every table in your DB, writing its contents out into a file and adding to the same file for each and every table.

Would that be useful somehow?
Probably not, as the structure of the data stored in the file would change for every block of data saved from a different table.

Your other question sort of implied that the data should be joined together by matching some ID column.
By using the `FULL OUTER JOIN` for that you basically say:
 *I don't care if there is a match or not, just put the data next to one another if there is.*

Does that sound about right?

Taking this together, the data structure you seem to hope for looks something like this:

```
(Table 1: col_ID, col_1, col_2, ...) + (Table 2: col_ID, col_1, col_23) ...
```

I've used '`+`' here to indicate "*glued together*".

This is the point in this discussion where you should realize that you try to solve a problem on a different level than what `SELECT` or `CREATE VIEW` can provide.

SQL is a static language, meaning that the data structures it works with are explicitly specified. 
It's never "*a table **like** this*" but always "*this **specific** table/column/view*"...

To achieve what you seem to be wanting to do, you would need to create a process that creates static SQL commands for your database.

Those static SQL commands would create the "glued together" dump of columns.

Fortunately for you, it's possible to write such a program.

**Generated SQL (not dynamic)**

SQL databases come with the database catalog that allows inspecting what tables are available and which columns all those tables have.

Your program would now need to go through all tables (that you consider relevant for this) and find out where column-names are used multiple times.

​For each of those collisions, you need to decide on how to deal with it (change output name, just use one of the columns, omit it altogether).

This processing stage results in a list of projected columns with unique column names (plus the source table references) and the joined tables.

Next is to transform this into valid SQL. That should be straight forward since the generalized structure of the statement is simply `SELECT ... <all your columns> FROM <table> OUTER JOIN <table> ...` .

**Applying the statement**

Now, you've created the output structure and the SELECT to fill it - you're back in "static type"-land and all your SQL tools work again.

Maybe you're familiar with Java and OO, if so, think of this as a

```
DB2FlatFileStatementFactory (IN db_catalog, OUT sql_statement)
```

kind of thing.

**Caveats**

With the approach to glue all data next to each other, you make the strong assumption that the data model is really just a set of otherwise independent tables with a maximum of one record per ID in each table. 
While possible this is a rather rare (and often bad/wrong) database design.

As your approach heavily relies on this assumption, you might want to consider checking if it holds true for every table (e.g. by checking that all ID columns are actually the full primary keys of the tables).

Anyhow, there you go, now you know how to do that.
(on practically any SQL DBMS, not just HANA)